# pgAdmin 4 v 6.8 cannot export Greek characters correctly

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, collation, pgadmin-4

I had pgAdmin4 v4 and I was using the query tool to execute a query, get data and use the "Save results to file (F8)" (arrow point to a disk) button to export query results to a csv. When there were Greek characters, they were exported correctly.

I upgraded to pgAdmin4 v6.8 , I do the same, and the characters are correct when I see the query result , but when I export it to csv , they are wrong, like "Ξ”ΞΉΞΏΟƒΞΊΞΏΟ". They should be something like οδός Σαρρή

I reinstalled pgAdmin4 v4, I installed pgAdmin 4 v6.5 and still the same issue.

The DB I create is

```
OWNER = postgres
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'Greek_Greece.1253'
LC_CTYPE = 'Greek_Greece.1253'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What should that string really look like? What encoding did you specify for the export?

Comment: It should be Greek words, now its just gibberish and not all characters are Greek. eg ƒ. It should be something like Οδος Σαρρη. I dont know how to set encoding during the export. Any help please? Thanks

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. I'd guess that your example `Οδος Σαρρη` is transformed to ```"ΞΞ΄ΞΏΟ‚ Ξ£Ξ±ΟΟΞ·"```?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to reproduce that on my pgAdmin4 6.8, and the export feature doesn't work at all :^(

However, the problem in your case is that the data are written with UTF-8 encoding rather than with Windows-1253.  You should be able to fix that by choosing `WIN1253` for "Encoding" in the export dialog that you get when you select the table and choose "Export" from the context menu. If that doesn't work, report it as a bug to the pgAdmin project.

There is no option to choose the encoding when you write a query result to a CSV file with <kbd>F8</kbd>. In that case, the file is encoded in UTF-8.

I recommend that you use `psql` rather than pgAdmin for this and use `\copy` directly. That's what pgAdmin4 does under the hood, and you might do better by avoiding pgAdmin in the first place.

Comment: After my query I click on the "Save results to file (F8)" button (arrow pointing to disk) , located in the Query editor toolbar. The only option there is to export as csv. I am on Windows 10. There is no Encoding setting. Sorry if I didn't made that clear

Comment: Try the "Export" dialog. If that fails too (as it does for me), report it as a bug.